# Problem with Python 3 rolling dice simulator

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm having some kind of problem with this code that should simulate a dice rolling simulator but i cant get out of my while loop again whatever i try.

```
import random

print('-------------------------------------------------------')
print('       WELCOME TO THE DICE ROLLING SIMULATOR')
print('-------------------------------------------------------')

while True:
    randomNumber = str(random.randint(1, 6))
    rollAgain = input('would you like to roll the dice? yes or no?')
    if rollAgain == 'yes' or ' yes':
        print('Rolling the dice')
        print('the dice landed on the number: ' + randomNumber)
   elif rollAgain == 'no' or ' no':
        quit()
```

Comment: `' yes'` will always be true

Comment: "while True" set you in an infinite loop.

Comment: @HectorIX - Thats irrelevant, the `quit()` will close the application

Comment: You are right. However this is not the best practice. It will be much better if you define a variable, set it to True and when choose 'No', then assign the False.

Comment: @HectorIX - I disagree, theres nothing wrong with it here, in fact in an environment that requires extremely strict memory management, the extra variable may even be a hinderance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the variable against the value everytime. In the line

```
if rollAgain == 'yes' or ' yes':
```

Python evaluates `' yes'` as `true` everytime. You need to compare it to `rollAgain` aswell.

Here's the fixed code:

```
import random

print('-------------------------------------------------------')
print('       WELCOME TO THE DICE ROLLING SIMULATOR')
print('-------------------------------------------------------')

while True:
    randomNumber = str(random.randint(1, 6))
    rollAgain = input('would you like to roll the dice? yes or no?')
    if rollAgain == 'yes' or rollAgain ==  ' yes':
        print('Rolling the dice')
        print('the dice landed on the number: ' + randomNumber)
    elif rollAgain == 'no' or rollAgain == ' no':
        quit()
```